# Complex-valued weight initialization in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a complex-valued (input,output) data, and I  wanted to train a fully complex network using keras in TensorFlow 2.0. I wrote a loss  function which returns real value, and customized it into keras. Similarly, I added some complex-valued activation functions in the hidden layer, and the model started to learn successfully. However, when I tried to customize the complex weight and bias initialization in a similar procedure, it gives  an error. For clarity here is what I tried to do.

```
def initialize_weight(shape, dtype= None):
    real = K.random_uniform(shape, dtype = dtype)
    imag = K.random_normal(shape, dtype=dtype)
    return  tf.complex(real,imag)
```

```
model_new = Sequential()
model_new.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x_train.shape[0],  kernel_initializer = initialize_weight,activation = myrelu))
model_new.add(Dense(10,  kernel_initializer = intilialize_weight, activation = myrelu)) 
model_new.add(Dense(y_train.shape[0], kernel_initializer = initialize_weight, activation = myrelu)) 
model_new.compile(loss= mse_error, optimizer='adam', metric = 'accuracy')
model_new.summary()
```

The error message is: * ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype complex64:

Notice that, the activation *myrelu* and the loss function *mse_error* are custom functions. The error is only due to the kernel_initializer. 
Is there a way to customize a complex-valued weight in keras please ? I really appreciate any support on this. Thanks !